# Android invalidateDarawable() not works

Tags: android, drawable, invalidation

Here is my **custom View's** code sample:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();

    d = new ShapeDrawable(new PathShape(path, getWidth(), getHeight()));
    path.moveTo(110, 110);
    path.lineTo(210, 110);
    d.getPaint().setColor(pathColor); 
    d.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
    d.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(3);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    d.draw(canvas);     
}

public void changePath (int color){
        pathColor = color;
        invalidate();
    }
```

It works good, when I call **changePath()** method.

But, if I change **invalidate()** to **invalidateDrawable(d)** - my **ShapeDrawable d** is not redrawn. Where is mistake?

Comment: then if invalidate work then dont use invalidateDrawable

Comment: why are you using that ShapeDrawable? why not canvas.drawPath() instead?

Comment: i use it cause i want to redraw specific path using invalidateDrawable(d)